# How to get multi language translation with parts of speech in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, translation, multilingual

I want to translate word in multiple langauges. I am using Bing Translator API. It is working fine.
But i want to know the Parts of Speech as well with language translation.
Suppose the word "book". It gives translation in desired langauge. But it given translation as noun.
But "book" is also a verb e.g "book a ticket". But API only gives translation for noun.

**Is there any other API or way to get all possible translations with Parts of speech as well.?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The statistical machine translation systems (like Bing and most others available today) are dumb to the part-of-speech concept - they work on segments (usually a sentence), so while "book" might be ambiguous, you will (usually) get correct translation when you send whole "book a ticket" phrase.

You could use an NLP API (e.g. MS Linguistic Analysis APIs) to get the part of speech tagging, but AFAIK you cannot use this information as an additional context for the machine translation.